# Show subreport multiple times based on multi-value parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, sql-server-data-tools

I have a report that shows aggrevated sales figures for one or more shops.
The shops can be selected through a multi-value parameter (shopID) that is used to filter a  shared dataset. The parameter shopid is filled by the shared dataset shops

This report contains a subreport that shows details per shop. The subreport has a single-value parameter (shopID) that is used to filter a shared dataset in the subreport.

now, when I link the subreport like this:

```
Parameters Tab on Properties page of the subreport:
Name = shopID  Value = Fields!shopid.Value
```

the subreport is shown *for each shopid in the dataset shops*. But I want the subreport to be shown for *each shopID in the parameter shopID*. I thought it would suffice to use the parameter for the value, like this:

```
Parameters Tab on Properties page of the subreport:
Name = shopID  Value = Parameters!LaagID.Value
```

But then I only get the first shop in the parameter returned. I get the subreport showing  the first shop as many times as there are shops.....If I use

```
Parameters Tab on Properties page of the subreport:
Name = shopID  Value = Parameters!LaagID.Value(1)
```

I get to see (surprise, surprise) the second shop as many times as there are shops.....

I have tried splits, joins, all kind of things but for the life of me I can not find out how to show the subreport once for each shop in the parameter shopid.

Suggestions? Pretty pretty please?

Comment: It seems that you could run parameter through another dataset which will return only selected shopIds (this is to turn parameter into something that can be processed by data region) Query might look like `Select shopId where shopId in (@shopId)`

Comment: The second I read it, I thought: "ofcourse!!!" Thank you so much. Please, put this in as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you could run parameter through another dataset which will return only selected shopIds (this is to turn parameter into something that can be processed by data region) Query might look like `Select shopId where shopId in (@shopId)`